# DTCoreText No such file or directory libDTCoreText.a

Tags: objective-c, xcode, dtcoretext

I am using DTCoreText ver. 1.0.1.
I installed it manually without using CocoaPods.
Installed with reference to here.
[Setup Guide Document](https://docs.cocoanetics.com/DTCoreText/docs/Setup%20Guide.html)

When building the project, the following error appears and the build cannot be performed.

```
No such file or directory: '/*****/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/libDTCoreText.a'
```

LibDTCoreText.a is added to **Link Binary With Libraries** of **Build Phases**.
Do you know what's wrong?

- Xcode : 10.3
- Language : Objective-C
- Deployment Target : 9.3